# Is it sensefully to compile explicitly for x64 with .net?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation, x86, 64-bit

Currently I am creating an MSI for installing my .net-written (C#) software on a x64-System. This is necessary because I generate some registry-entries and I don't want to decide programmatically to which registry-path I have to point (avoiding WOW6432-node).

During this I ask myself, if it is necessary to compile my software explicitly for x64-systems (Run-Configuration "x64"). Currently I always compile my software in Visual Studio platform agnostic with "Any CPU". In my source code I do not differentiate between x64 and x86.

The CIL-code is compiled by the JIT-compiler, so I think it will explicitly compile it to 64bit on runtime, or am I wrong?

What are the differences between the explicit "x64"-compiling and the platform agnostic compiling in visual studio?
How influences the x64-flag the compilation?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064.aspx

Comment: When you are sure it will only run on x64 machines, compile it as x64. The same applies to x86 cases. Only if you want to enjoy the flexibility of AnyCPU as those articles indicate, you should leave it as AnyCPU.

Comment: It had to run on both, An alternative to the language agnostic form would be to compile for the several targets and to bind the binaries dependent on platform the MSI, but currently I see no advantage doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your program (With Any CPU) is launched on a 64-bit platform it will start in 64-bit mode. This will often work very well - the exception is if you program relies on native libraries *for which only a 32-bit version* is available. It will then fail to load that library when the call to it is hit (so any problem might not be immediately apparent).

It's also possible to force 32-bit mode using flags at runtime.